# UITextView white opaque backgroundcolor to improve performance

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitextview

I want to make the background of a UITextView solid white and opaque in order to improve performance.

I've tried this without any luck:

```
textView.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
textView.opaque = YES;
```

It still shows Blended Layer in the simulator. Does anyone know of a workaround for this?

Comment: From [Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/opaque), "You only need to set a value for the opaque property for subclasses of UIView that draw their own content using the drawRect: method. The opaque property has no effect for system provided classes such as UIButton, UILabel, UITableViewCell, etc." so you don't need the `opaque = YES`.

Comment: That said, what do you mean by "without any luck"? Not opaque? No performance gain? Have you profiled to see where the performance bottleneck is? Perhaps the rounded corners on the text view are the problem. Perhaps try adding it to a wrapper view and making that one white and opaque.

Comment: In fact opaque white color is default in a UITextView.

Comment: Color Blended Layers is still showing the UITextView to be "blended" vs. a UILabel with the background color set to white would not be?